Virtualization Issues on Server Without Hardware Support
I’m experiencing issues during the installation and configuration of a virtual machine on a server that unfortunately does not support hardware virtualization. I ran the following command to check for support of virtualization extensions:
root@Aldin:~# egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo

The result is 0, which indicates that the virtualization extensions (vmx for Intel and svm for AMD) are not enabled in the BIOS or are unavailable on the CPU. This prevents the use of virtualization technologies like KVM (Kernel-based Virtual Machine), significantly limiting options for efficiently running virtual machines.
I also attempted to use QEMU-based virtualization environments but without success, as the lack of hardware support results in poor performance and significant limitations.
Has anyone had similar experiences or can suggest practical alternatives? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!
